# Thermal Noise Sampling on Capacitors

Tags: capacitor

[image]

[ From Marcel Pelgrom's Analog-to-Digital Conversion ,pg34]

I was reading this example from the noise sampling section and I am bit confused. **Why does he say that the noise contributions from each capacitor will cancel?**

My understanding is as follows:

1. In the first configuration, the signal Vin is sampled on both capacitors and the thermal noise is based on the parallel equivalent capacitance of $$C1+C2$$. Thus the noise is $$kT/(C1+C2) = kT/(2C1)$$. Thus, the total SNR is $$(2C1Vin)/kT$$
2. After the capacitors are reoriented in a series configuration, we can combine the two series capacitors to have an equivalent capacitance of $$C1/2$$. The total signal voltage also doubles to 2Vin. Thus, the total noise on this new configuration is $$kT/(C1/2) = 2kT/C1$$. Thus, the new SNR is $$2C1Vin/2kT = C1Vin/kT$$

Thus, the SNR is halved in this new confgiuration? I don't understand how he is saying that they cancel eachother?

Do I have to account for the thermal noise caused by the first sampling moment when analysing the second configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the signal power incorrectly (the noise calculation is correct). Signal power is half of square of the signal voltage:
$$S = \frac{V_{in}^2}{2}$$
In the first case:
$$SNR = \frac{V_{in}^2}{2}/\frac{kT}{2C} = \frac{V_{in}^2C}{kT}$$

In second case:
$$SNR = \frac{(2V_{in})^2}{2}/\frac{2kT}{C} = \frac{V_{in}^2C}{kT}$$
Thus it is same in both cases.

Comment: Ah. I see. One more question, when the second sampling event happens, do you still in your head think of the thermal noise from the first sampling event to be present on the capacitor voltages? I understand it's a random stochastic process, so it doesn't really make sense to think of the first thermal noise having any effect right?

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is that when the second sampling event happens, you can pretty much disregard whatever thermal noise was caused by the first sampling event right?